# Angular named router outlet not routed to?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

[This demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gdo4zu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts) has 2 outlets (Defined in `app.module.ts` :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="b"></router-outlet>
```

These routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'a', component: HelloComponent },
  { path: 'b', outlet: 'b', component: HelloComponent },
];
```

And these buttons to test the routes ( In `app.component.html` ).

```
<button routerLink="a">router link a</button>
<button routerLink="b">router link b</button>
```

Route a works.  However when clicking route b this error is created:

```
ERROR
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'b'
Error: Cannot match any routes.
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`routerLink` is always using the primary outlet by default, you must specify the outlet in order to navigate to it. In your case:

```
<a [routerLink]="[{ outlets: { 'b': ['b'] } }]">Component Aux</a>
```

The error makes sense since there is no route named `b` defined for the primary outlet.